# NHibernate.Linq : session becomes dirty after select

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate

I have a simple NHiberntate linq query:

```
var queryable = session.Linq<Product>().Where(p => p.Active);
Product[] products = queryable.ToArray();
```

The moment the `ToArray()` is executed the session becomes dirty (`session.IsDirty()` returns `true`). If the transaction is commited there is an UPDATE SQL query generated for each product.

Why are the products marked as dirty after a simple SQL SELECT?

In this project we are using the folowing framework/tools:

- .Net 3.5 + WPF
- NHibernate 2.1.2 + FluentNHibernate
- SQlite
- PostSharp 1.5

Comment: This is not a linq problem, but a mapping problem. Post your mapping, entity and related database schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem is called "Ghost"

this test will detect this kind of problems:
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-test-your-mappings-ghostbuster.html

this is my improvement, is a little bit more verbose, and thus it will give you more information:
http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/02/nhibernate-ghostbuster-version-11.html

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. I used a plain SQL script to intialize the data and some columns mapped to int properties where initialized to NULL. 
Your test passed tho, I think it's because it only tests the first entity of each type.